# RamdaJS - How can I use pipe with sync and async functions?

Tags: ramda.js

I'm trying to learn Ramda and how to use it on my daily work. So I have a quick question. "How can I use pipe with sync and async functions?" or best, how can I improve the following code?

```
const AuthService = () => ({
  async signIn(credentials: Credentials): Promise<AuthSession> {
    const result = await api.signIn(credentials)

    return R.pipe(
      signInResultToAuthSession,
      saveAuthSession
    )(result)
  }
})
```

[EDITED]: A second alternative that I think be better.

```
const AuthService = () => ({
  async signIn(credentials: Credentials): Promise<AuthSession> {
    return api.signIn(credentials).then(
      R.pipe(
        signInResultToAuthSession,
        saveAuthSession
      )
    )
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pipeWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipeWith) was added for just such cases.  It wraps the functions in a common interface (here `then`) and passes the results along, just like `pipe`.

```js
const api = {signIn: ({pwd, ...creds}) => Promise.resolve({...creds, signedIn: true})}
const signInResultToAuthSession = (creds) => Promise.resolve({...creds, auth: true})
const saveAuthSession = (creds) => Promise.resolve({...creds, saved: true})

const AuthService = {
  signIn: pipeWith(then)([
    api.signIn, // [1]
    signInResultToAuthSession,
    saveAuthSession
  ])
}

AuthService.signIn({name: 'fred', pwd: 'flintstone'})
  .then(console.log)

// [1]: `bind` might be necessary here, depending on the design of `api.signIn`
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {pipeWith, then} = R                                   </script>
```

Do note that `pipeWith` wraps the functions in an array.  One day we'd like to do the same with `pipe`, but that's a hugely breaking change.

Comment: Note that `then` was renamed to `andThen` in Ramda 0.27, see [here](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/2772)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function like this:

```js
const then = f => p => p.then(f)
```

And then your pipe would look like:

```js
const AuthService = () => ({
  async signIn(credentials: Credentials): Promise<AuthSession> {
    return R.pipe(
      api.signIn,
      then(signInResultToAuthSession),
      then(saveAuthSession),
    )(credentials)
  }
})
```

You could even catch exceptions with:

```js
const pCatch = f => p => p.catch(f)
```

```js
R.pipe(
   api.signIn,
   pCatch(err => console.error(err)),
   then(signInResultToAuthSession),
   then(saveAuthSession),
)(credentials)
```

Comment: I think you could use `R.then` and `R.otherwise` too.

Comment: @customcommander Oh nice, I didn't know Ramda added a `then` function. Good to know.